# Paging in BootStrap Model Pop UP Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am New To ASP.Net MVC . I am showing some Data In Pop UP Using BootStrap Model .Basically usually for each loop  i am displaying Data .The Question is How To apply paging in these scenario using PagedList.MVC or any other think .

Thanks For Help.

Comment: Hard to help without codel You should paste your code from view and controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example using [WebGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/615776/WebGrid-in-ASP-NET-MVC) and twitter bootstrap.

**Controller:**

```
public class Info
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ModalPopup()
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_GetPartial.cshtml", GetItems());
        else
            return View();
    }

    public PartialViewResult _GetPartial()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_GetPartial.cshtml",GetItems());
    }

    private List<Info> GetItems()
    {
        var item1 = new Info { Description = "Item 1", Number = "1" };
        var item2 = new Info { Description = "Item 2", Number = "2" };
        var item3 = new Info { Description = "Item 3", Number = "3" };

        var item4 = new Info { Description = "Item 4", Number = "4" };
        var item5 = new Info { Description = "Item 5", Number = "5" };
        var item6 = new Info { Description = "Item 6", Number = "6" };

        var item7 = new Info { Description = "Item 7", Number = "7" };
        var item8 = new Info { Description = "Item 8", Number = "8" };
        var item9 = new Info { Description = "Item 9", Number = "9" };

        return new List<Info> { item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9 };
    }
}
```

**_GetPartial.cshtml(partial view):**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication7.Controllers.Info>


@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, canSort: false, rowsPerPage: 3, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
 }
<div id="grid">
    @if (Model.Any())
    {
        @grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle: "table",
columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("Nr", "Nr", format: @<text> @item.Number
    </text>, style: "p13"),
    grid.Column("Description","Description", format: @<text> @item.Description</text>)))
    }
</div>
```

**Main view(ModalPopup.cshtml):**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#showModal").click(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="button" value="Show Modal" id="showModal" />
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Grid inside modal popup</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Html.Action("_GetPartial","Home")
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And this is how it looks:**

[image: Displaying grid with paging inside a modal popup]

Comment: Thanks For The Answer